# Why does let not give me a non nullable integer in this case

Tags: kotlin, nullable

Fairly new to Kotlin - I'm slightly confused by why
when using let in this example 'it' is still nullable?
As a result the example fails to compile

> Error:(9, 20) Type mismatch: inferred type is Int? but Int was
>   expected

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val myNewNullableInt: Int? =6
    myNewNullableInt.let{
        printAnInteger(it)
    }

}

fun printAnInteger (integerToPrint: Int){
    println(integerToPrint)
}
```

Example:
https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/fnlicstrn4tbmk8gs071vmv4ka/9dd72cr92ikggh3g9qg981h01o

Comment: just as a further side-note... you need `?.`, but you probably do not need `let` here... if it's just printing what you want, you could do: `myNewNullableInt?.run(::println)` (or same with `?.also`)... You only need `let` if you actually want to return or set a value which is calculated and returned within the given body...

Comment: Thanks Roland this was just a simplified example from something more complex I was doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let {}` doesn't change the type of the variable. What you want to do is making it null-safe. This is done with the `?.` access

```
myNewNullableInt?.let{
    printAnInteger(it)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this answer could be clearer that it only smart-casts the value to a non-nullable type if it isn't actually null!  If it **is** null, then the safe-call `?.` operator will bypass the `let` block entirely.  Often that's what you want; but it's always worth thinking through the what-ifs.

Answer (score 1):

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

You have to use the safe call operator, written `?.`

> To perform a certain operation only for non-null values, you can use
>   the safe call operator together with let:
>
> ```
> val listWithNulls: List<String?> = listOf("Kotlin", null)
> for (item in listWithNulls) {   
>     item?.let { println(it) } // prints A and ignores null
> }
> ```

---

### Other options:

As second option you can use the !!-operator (use with care, it will throw a NPE if it is null)

```
val myNewNullableInt: Int? =6
myNewNullableInt!!.let{ //throws if myNewNullableInt == null
    printAnInteger(it)
}
```

Because you are using a non-mutable `val` you can also use `if(myNewNullableInt != null). Kotlin will recognize the null-check and auto-cast to the non-nullable type. You can see the smart-cast by the green marking of AndroidStudio or Idea.

```
val myNewNullableInt: Int? =6
   if(myNewNullableInt != null) {
           printAnInteger(myNewNullableInt )
   }
```

[image]

Comment: The link and more information (comes with the edit).